# Find the boundary pixels of binary mask in Julia

Tags: julia, image-segmentation, mathematical-morphology

I am trying to do image processing on an image in Julia. I have a binary mask for a region of interest within my image. I need to find the border of pixels just outside of my mask. In python I can use `skimage.segmentation.find_boundaries`, and in Matlab I can use `boundarymask`. Does Julia have any convenient tools to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I found a quick and dirty solution using PyCall which I will post for now, but if anyone finds a better solution that uses standard Julia modules I will accept that answer over mine.

```
using Conda
using PyCall

Conda.add("scikit-image")

find_boundaries = pyimport("skimage.segmentation").find_boundaries

mask = # load mask ...

border = find_boundaries(mask)
```

Comment: There is a [boundary_map](https://github.com/lucianolorenti/ImageSegmentationEvaluation.jl/blob/master/src/utils.jl#L61) function that works for binary masks, but the package it's in has been abandoned. The code is simple enough though, you can copy it to your project (and improve upon it!).